# Running unit tests after starting elasticsearch

Tags: bash, elasticsearch, jenkins

I've downloaded and set up elasticsearch on an EC2 instance that I use to run Jenkins. I'd like to use Jenkins to run some unit tests that use the local elasticsearch.

My problem is that I haven't found a way on how to start the elasticsearch locally and run the tests after, since the script doesn't proceed after starting ES, because the job is not killed or anything.

I can do this by starting ES manually through SSH and then building a project with only the unit tests. However, I'd like to automate the ES launching.

Any suggestions on how I could achieve this? I've tried now using single "Execute shell" block and two "Execute shell" blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is happening because you starting elasticsearch command in blocking way. It means command will wait until elasticsearch server is shutdown. Jenkins just keep waiting.

You can use following command

```
./elasticsearch 2>&1 >/dev/null &
```

or

```
nohup ./elasticsearch 2>&1 >/dev/null &
```

it will run command in non-blocking way.

You can also add small delay to allow elasticsearch server start

```
nohup ./elasticsearch 2>&1 >/dev/null &; sleep 5
```

Comment: What does the 2>&1 >/dev/null & part do? For some reason my tests can not get a connection to the Elasticsearch even though I have sleep set. This is the error I get:

`requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9200): Max retries exceeded with url: /test-events (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7efedc1dbd68>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))`

EDIT: I had to increase the sleep

Comment: 2>&1 redirects stderr to stdout. More info here https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redirecting-stderr-to-stdout/